# Can i modify the docker image provided by playwright to add custom node version

Tags: docker, testing, playwright

I was utilizing Playwright to test my frontend application at work, however, we use node version 16.15.0 specifically. But, while looking at the docker file by Playwright I see that they install the latest node version which is causing issues when running in CircleCi.

Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround? Would I have to create a custom docker image using Playwright's image to tackle this and install the correct node version?

Any help would be appreciated!

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/main/utils/docker/Dockerfile.focal.

https://playwright.dev/docs/docker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be the way to go. The best way to go about this would be to patch the `Dockerfile.focal` with an `ARG` instruction. You will then be able to pass values to this argument with your `docker build` command. This is the best approach that will make maintenance easier. Edit the `Dockerfile.focal` and add this variable as:

```
# leave this blank or specify a default value.
ARG NODE_VERSION=
```

Then in `docker build` you can set the value for this as. The `docker build` command in the script on the repo will change as follows:

```
docker build --platform "${PLATFORM}" -t "$3" -f "Dockerfile.$2" --build-arg NODE_VERSION=16.15.0 .
```

This will inject this variable into the image when it is being built so you can have the correct version. Also, this will make it easier to maintain since you will not have to change the `Dockerfile` every time you upgrade the version of NodeJS in your image.

Now, finally, you can edit the `build.sh` script to use the version variable. You can edit the line 13 in the script to something like:

```
    apt-get install -y nodejs="{NODE_VERSION}" && \
```

You can use `apt search nodejs` after running the `setup` script to verify the correct version of the package.

Comment: quick question, i tried running playwright in CircleCi without actually adding the docker image and it kind of works. Are you aware of what the actual purpose this image would serve me then?https://playwright.dev/docs/ci#circleci

Comment: You described your issue to be related to Node version, so I provided a solution on that. If it turns out that your initial assessment of the error was incorrect, feel free to add an update to the question :)

Comment: unsure about the assessment of the error as it is hard to pinpoint it but I was asking for my knowledge purposes.

Comment: If you could provide the `issues with CircleCI`, it would be easier to decide if Node version is indeed the culprit.  Some logs, perhaps?

Comment: @TanDev i don't get your point, i don't think it's possible to not specify a docker image. can you clarify, did you successfully use a more generic docker image?